# Adjust the tree parameters for a specific tree node

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I use `DecisionTreeClassifier` from `sklearn`

I need to correct splitter (feature), `min_samples_leaf` used in the particular tree node.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the `min_samples_leaf` for a single node, because the model would probably end up assigning fewer samples to other nodes than the `min_samples_leaf` of the whole model to ensure compliance with the rule applicable to this individual node.

If you are dealing with imbalanced data set, I suggest you [oversample or undersample](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/undersampling-and-oversampling-imbalanced-data) your data prior to inputting in the model or you could manually set the class weights.

According to [scikit-learn's user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tips-on-practical-use):

> Balance your dataset before training to prevent the tree from being
> biased toward the classes that are dominant. Class balancing can be
> done by sampling an equal number of samples from each class, or
> preferably by normalizing the sum of the sample weights
> (sample_weight) for each class to the same value.